# loop is executed but with and undefined offset message

Tags: php

what is wrong here:

```
$count = count($_POST['ids']);

for ($x=0; $x<=$count; $x++) {
    $sql = "update home set status = :astatus where id = :aid";
    $st = $db->prepare($sql);
    $st->execute(array(
        ":astatus" => $_POST['stats'][$x],
        ":aid" => $_POST['ids'][$x]
    ));
}
```

Error: `Undefined offset 40...`

As I can see in database - the code is executed.

checking:

```
echo $count; // 40  

echo count($_POST['stats']);  //40
```

Why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Most likely `$x<=$count` should be `$x<$count`

Comment: You only need to prepare the statement once, so you can move this outside the loop.

Comment: Nigel, thanks a lot, you comments are in fact - answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the following `for`:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) { //without =
    //...
}
```

The 39th element on your `$_POST['ids']` array is the 40th element since arrays starting at 0:

```
$arr = $_POST['ids'];
$arr[0]  // 1st
$arr[1]  // 2nd
// ...
$arr[38] // 39th
$arr[39] // 40th
```

---

The code can look like the following:

```
$arr_ids = $_POST['ids'];
$arr_stats = $_POST['stats'];
$count = count($arr_ids);

if ($count !== count($arr_stats)) {
    //TODO - what is happening if the count of stats and ids are different?
}

$st = $db->prepare("UPDATE home SET status = :astatus WHERE id = :aid");

for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {
    $st->execute(array(
        ":astatus" => $arr_stats[$x],
        ":aid" => $arr_ids[$x]
    ));
}
```